# Working out taxable income Java

Tags: java

I have just finished a Java test at university and I know that I have answered a particular question wrong and would just like some help / clarification please?

The question was as follows:

implement a method that takes someones income and works out the tax.
If that person earns less than 7500 then tax = 0.
If that person earns between 7501 and 45000 then tax = 20%, less the 7500, which is tax free.
Finally, if that person earns above 45001 then tax = 40%, less the income in the 20% bracket, and then less the 7500 which is tax free.

As time was running short, I just did a basic if else statement showing income and tax brackets, example below.

```
public static double incomeTax(double income){

    if(income <= 7500){
           income = income * 0;
       }
     else if(income >= 7501 && income <= 45000){
           income = income * 0.8;
       }
     else(income >= 45001){
           income = income * 0.6;
       }
     return income;
}
```

I know that the code is not correct, no where near, but as it was coming to the end of the test I gave it a go in a hope just to get a mark for the if else statements.

I would really appreciate any help here.

Thank you.

After great feedback, this is what I came back with (with a LOT of help!!:] )...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxableIncome
{
public static void main(String[] args){
    netIncome();
}

public static double netIncome() {
    double income = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter income: ");
    income = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    double tax1 = 0;
    double tax2 = 0;
    double totalTax = tax1 + tax2;

    // high income bracket
    if (income > 45000) {
        double part1 = income - 45000; // part = income - 45000
        tax1 += part1 * 0.4; // tax = tax + part * 0.4
        System.out.println("High Tax Band - Greater than 45000: " + tax1);
    }

    // medium income bracket
    if (income >  7500) {
        double part2 = income - 7500;
        tax2 += part2 * 0.2;
        System.out.println("Medium Tax Band - Greater than 7500: " + tax2);
    }

    System.out.println("Total Tax = " + (tax1 + tax2));

    // tax for low income is zero, we don't need to compute anything.

    return totalTax;
   }
}
```

Comment: It says `If that person earns between 7501 and 45000 then tax = 20%` but you multiply `income` by 8, why? I think this is more about mathematics than programming in your case.

Comment: Yeah, I get hit in the head a lot...
Thanks though.
Actually, yes, total screw up.

Comment: Do not use `double` or `float` for money values.  Money is fixed decimal not floating decimal.  Instead represent your money values in the smallest denomination (ex pennies in the USA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer would be as this:

```
public static double netIncome(double income) {

  double tax = 0;

  // high income bracket
  if (income > 45000) {
    double part = income - 45000;
    tax += part * 0.4;
    income = 45000;
  }

  // medium income bracket
  if (income >  7500) {
    double part = income - 7500;
    tax += part * 0.2;
  }

  // tax for low income is zero, we don't need to compute anything.

  return tax;
}
```

This way you calculate the tax for each tax bracket and sum them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback here. This was really useful. Shame about my math...  :[

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with the logic. The main issue you had was you just need to return the income tax, not the total income.  So the value you needed to return was income*whateverPercentTax.

Also, I would've tried:

```
if(income < 7001){
}else if(income >=45001){
}else{}
```

But that is just me.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to tax things in bands. Dirty (untested) code:

```
public static double incomeTax(double income){
    double tax = 0;
    if(income > 7500){
        tax += Math.min(45000-7500, income-7500)*.2;
    }

    if(income > 45000){
        tax += (income-45000)*.4;
    }
    return tax;
}
```

Comment: I ran this through my unit tests and found these problems: Math.max should be Math.min on line 4. income - 45000 should be (income - 45000) on line 8.

Comment: @richj right on all accounts :) Like I said quick hack directly on the site. Thanks for checking it! I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to attempt to apply the tax rates more than once. Your code only hits one tax bracket. If I made 100k, I would have been taxed at 40% for the whole 100k. Here is something I came up with quickly.

```
public static double incomeTax(double income)
{
    double tax = 0.0;
    int midLevel = 7500;
    int highLevel = 45000;

    if (income <= 7500)
    {
        // Could early exit at this point and return already set tax
        tax = 0.0;
    }

    if (income > midLevel)
    {
        // Find range of income > 7500, less than 4500. 37499 max
        double taxableIncome = Math.min(income - midLevel, highLevel - midLevel - 1);
        tax += taxableIncome * 0.2;
    }

    if (income > highLevel)
    {
        // Income above 45k
        double taxableIncome = income - highLevel;
        tax += taxableIncome * 0.4;
    }

    return tax;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help here. Most helpful.
I will now use this and build on it. 
With regards to the mathematics, I actually used something similar to what we was working on in class, in that working out a 10% discount.
So, for a 10% discount would use discount = discount * 0.9.
I have obviously got this wrong in my original post.

But thank you all again. Great feedback.

Comment: I ran this through my unit tests and found these problems: tax needs to be initialized in order to get this to compile - at least with JDK 1.7. On line 10 7501 should be 7500. Income above 45000 is taxed with both 20% and 40% rates for a total of 60%.

Comment: @richj - I changed it and it ends up like the solution Miquel posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this:

```
public static double incomeTax(int income) {
    final double band00Income = (double) Math.min(income, 7500);
    final double band20Income = (double) Math.min(income - band00Income, 45000 - 7500);
    final double band40Income = (double) Math.max(income - 45000, 0);

    final double tax = band20Income * 0.2 + band40Income * 0.4;

    return tax;
}
```

Note that income is an int due to a peculiarity of the tax calculation in the UK - it also solves the problem with the unspecified cases between 7500.01 and 7500.99 inclusive.

A better solution would extract constants for all the magic numbers. An even better solution would generalise the bands and rates into a table so that they can be changed easily.

A complete answer might include test cases like this:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestTax
{
    public static final double DELTA = 0.1;

    @Test
    public void testTax() {
        Assert.assertEquals(0.0, incomeTax(-3000), DELTA);
        Assert.assertEquals(0.0, incomeTax(0), DELTA);
        Assert.assertEquals(0.2, incomeTax(7501), DELTA);
        Assert.assertEquals(3000.0, incomeTax(22500), DELTA);
        Assert.assertEquals(7500.0, incomeTax(45000), DELTA);
        Assert.assertEquals(7500.4, incomeTax(45001), DELTA);
        Assert.assertEquals(25500.0, incomeTax(90000), DELTA);
    }

    public static double incomeTax(int income) {
        final double band00Income = (double) Math.min(income, 7500);
        final double band20Income = (double) Math.min(income - band00Income, 45000 - 7500);
        final double band40Income = (double) Math.max(income - 45000, 0);

        final double tax = band20Income * 0.2 + band40Income * 0.4;

        return tax;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would not even know where to start!!
But this is something to aspire to!! Thank you. =]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, just copy your income brackets in the **bracket** array. Make sure you have *infinity* in **bracket** array and start with *0* in **rate** array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class IncomeTaxWithBrackets {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double infinity = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double [] bracket = {0, 7565, 25903, 54987, 121121, 567894, infinity}; 
    double [] rate = {0, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35};
    // bracket[0] to bracket[1] are assigned rate[1]

    double income = 0;
    double tax = 0;

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your income: ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat ("$#,##0.00");

    income = keyboard.nextDouble();

    int x,i;

    for (i=0; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (income > bracket[i] && income <= bracket[i+1]) {
            for (x=0; x<i; ++x) {
                tax = tax + (bracket[x+1] - bracket[x]) * rate[x+1];
            }   
            tax = tax + (income - bracket[i]) * rate[i+1];
        }
    }       
    System.out.println("\nWith a taxable income of "+dollar.format(income)+", your personal income tax is "+dollar.format(tax));
}
  }
```

Let me know what you think.